# how to count AVERAGE hourly visits with google spreadsheets & google analytics api

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-analytics-api

Hi I need a graph with average hourly visits for each day of the week. It will count averages from last 3 months.

I used "google analytics magic script" to pull hourly visits to google spreadsheet, now I don't know how to efficiently count the averages.
this is the table i've got, i can't insert an image (i'm a new member) so i have to describe

- column A is date
- column B is hour of the day (0,1,2,3,4...)
- column C is number of visits
- column D calculates the day of the week   (Sa,Su,M,Tu,W,Th...)
- column E combines the day and hour (Sa0, Sa1)

  now i need to average all visit values corresponding to all Sa0, Sa1 etc. Does it make sense?

I know i could sort the sheet according to column E and then count it manually, but i want to use a formula so I can create an automatic report.

Thanks a lot

```
A          B    C    D   E
date     hour visits day day+hour
9/8/2012    0   9   Sa  Sa0
9/8/2012    1   8   Sa  Sa1
9/8/2012    2   1   Sa  Sa2
9/8/2012    3   2   Sa  Sa3
9/8/2012    4   2   Sa  Sa4
9/8/2012    5   5   Sa  Sa5
9/8/2012    6   12  Sa  Sa6
9/8/2012    7   23  Sa  Sa7
9/8/2012    8   53  Sa  Sa8
9/8/2012    9   42  Sa  Sa9
9/8/2012    10  59  Sa  Sa10
9/8/2012    11  56  Sa  Sa11
9/8/2012    12  67  Sa  Sa12
9/8/2012    13  66  Sa  Sa13
9/8/2012    14  70  Sa  Sa14
9/8/2012    15  81  Sa  Sa15
9/8/2012    16  54  Sa  Sa16
9/8/2012    17  62  Sa  Sa17
9/8/2012    18  44  Sa  Sa18
9/8/2012    19  75  Sa  Sa19
9/8/2012    20  101 Sa  Sa20
9/8/2012    21  80  Sa  Sa21
9/8/2012    22  68  Sa  Sa22
9/8/2012    23  27  Sa  Sa23
9/9/2012    0   27  Su  Su0
9/9/2012    1   4   Su  Su1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly:

`=QUERY(C:E;"select E, avg(C) where E != '' group by E label avg(C) 'Average Visits'";1)`

[QUERY function](http://support.google.com/drive/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1388882)